# Epiphany Browser is unable to display HTML5 Video

Tags: html, raspberry-pi, epiphany

I installed latest RaspberryPI OS and it has a default browser (Epiphany) on my RPI.

I want to run my simple html5 webpage having a video, but browser is displaying only video controls and do not display and stream video.

I use html5test.com for checking the supporting videos format, (webm) and it is supporting my uploaded video (My video have Webm vp9 codec and another one is having MPEG-4)

Videos are working fine on ubuntu, windows and mac browsers but problem arise only at raspberry pi, any configuration or some other tools installation is required??

Any suggestion or idea why Epiphany browser is not running my video??

Answer (score 1):

Are you in the "audio" group? If not, `sudo adduser <username> audio`. You must also be in the "video" group. I wasn't in audio, and I was getting this error because the player stops once it can't find the "default" audio output (since you don't have permissions to access it).